# Zend Framework Hostname Routing and Default Route

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-route

I created a Hostname route like this:

```
$siteRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':siteSlug.wordy',
    array(
        'siteSlug' => 'main-site',
        'module' => 'default'
    )
);
```

and i chain it with default and other rotues like this:

```
foreach ($router->getRoutes() as $key => $route) {
    $router->addRoute($key, $siteRoute->chain($route));
}
```

The problems are:

When i got to `main-site.wordy` there is no problem. but if i go to just `wordy` i get this error message: `No route matched the request`

And the other problem is when i go to `wordy/admin` i get this exception: `Invalid controller specified (admin)`

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest u to make a htaccess redirect for non www url to 301 redirect on www.wordy in this way u always have :sitename for router hostname !

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wordy$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.wordy/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: other solution is creating router_route in this way u get arround acess without subdomain and can route normaly for your default siteSlug "main-site"